# Append result of more cursors in one in Oracle

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle12c, resultset

I have several procedures of this type:

```
sp_a(V_MIN INT, V_MAX INT, sc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
sp_b(V_MIN INT, V_MAX INT, sc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
...
sp_n(num_mV_MIN n INT, num_max INT, sc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
```

The result set of all stored procedures has the same columns output, I need a procedure that hangs the results of the n procedures in one.

I tried to create a similar procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_final(V_MIN INT, V_MAX INT, FIN_CURS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
num_min INT := V_MIN;
num_max INT:= V_MAX;

BEGIN

sp_a (num_min, num_max, FIN_CURS);
sp_b (num_min, num_max, FIN_CURS);

END;
```

but it only pulls out the result of the sp_b stored procedure. Is there any other way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the function:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_a (v_min INT, v_max INT, sc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN sc FOR
  SELECT v_min + (LEVEL - 1) AS value
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= v_max - v_min + 1;
END;
/
```

Then you can `BULK COLLECT` the cursor values into collections and then create a new cursor:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_final(v_min INT, v_max INT, sc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
  sc_a SYS_REFCURSOR;
  sc_b SYS_REFCURSOR;
  
  v_a int_list;
  v_b int_list;
BEGIN
  sp_a(v_min, v_max, sc_a);
  sp_a(v_min, v_max, sc_b);
  
  FETCH sc_a BULK COLLECT INTO v_a;
  FETCH sc_b BULK COLLECT INTO v_b;
  
  CLOSE sc_a;
  CLOSE sc_b;
  
  OPEN sc FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS value FROM TABLE(v_a)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_b);
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_val INT;
BEGIN
  sp_final(1, 3, v_sc);
  LOOP
    FETCH v_sc INTO v_val;
    EXIT WHEN v_sc%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_val);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE v_sc;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 1
> 2
> 3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=62ed4a7c42aeacf8ea5ede0b9e079b83)*